# What is the best way to both secure input and allow some html tags?

Tags: php, security, zend-framework, filtering, xss

It's a long time that I wonder the best way to both secure input and allow some html tags in some particular cases.

The typical situation is an admin who wants to write an article on xss (for example), which will be stored in a database, and will be shown to the users. This admin would have the chance to write tags like `<b>` to format the text but also like `<javascript>` to explain the attack. If I use `Zend_Filter_StripTags` I can allow the admin to put harmless html tag like `<b>` in the text but, for security reason, I cannot allow him to put tags like `<javascript>`.

On the other hand, if I use `Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities` I allow the admin to write every tags safely but when the article is shown, the text is not formatted. At last, if I use `Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities` and a decode method before the system shows the article, I've the same problem of the first case.

Does anyone know the best method to solve this problem?

Comment: To summarize: you want to htmlspecialchars() your input, while leaving some tags unescaped.

Comment: you could make a BBCode like language and then convert to something safe server side. i.e. [javascript]  is converted to &lt;javascript&gt; . Strip the tags first and then convert the [] tags.

Comment: @Joseph Shanak: Of course your answer is interesting but I want to solve this problem using filters or other similar classes already in the zend framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities to escape all HTML tags and then use [`Zend_Markup`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.markup.html) to provide formatting via BBCode annotations.

Answer (score 3):

Use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/):

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant    HTML filter library written
>   in    PHP. HTML Purifier will not only remove all malicious    code
>   (better known as XSS) with a thoroughly audited,    secure yet
>   **permissive whitelist**,   it will also make sure your documents are
>   standards compliant, something only achievable with a    comprehensive
>   knowledge of W3C's specifications.

Comment: I believe HTMLPurifier just removes the non-whitelisted tags; can it escape them instead ? (if not, this doesn't answer OP's question)

Comment: op would also have to escape with a separate function but this is still the answer. if op needs it in one function than he can make his own that does both steps with the input.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTMLPurifier

http://htmlpurifier.org/

It can sanitize the input as well as tidying up the HTML

Comment: I believe HTMLPurifier just removes the non-whitelisted tags; can it escape them instead ? (if not, this doesn't answer OP's question)